# AngularJS Ngdraggable issue

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ngdraggable

I'm working on making an draggable div element for a project I'm supporting. I found this [AngularJS directive](http://codepen.io/vcelis/pen/Emvud) that allows an element to be draggable.

I modified the directive to change the starting position, but when I made the change the mouse direction is not inverted (i.e. move the mouse to the right, the div moves to the left). Here is an updated version of the [AngularJS directive](http://codepen.io/herrjosuab/pen/YZveeZ) with the changes below to showcase the issue I'm encountering.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {

});

app.directive('ngDraggable', function($document, $window){
  function makeDraggable(scope, element, attr) {
    var startX = 0;
    var startY = 0;

    var x = 20;
    var y = 20;

    // Start with a random pos
    // var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 500) + 40);
    // var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 360) + 40);

    element.css({
      position: 'absolute',
      cursor: 'pointer',
      bottom: y + 'px',
      right: x + 'px'
    });

    element.on('mousedown', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      startX = event.pageX - x;
      startY = event.pageY - y;

      $document.on('mousemove', mousemove);
      $document.on('mouseup', mouseup);
    });

    function mousemove(event) {
      y = event.pageY - startY;
      x = event.pageX - startX;

      element.css({
        bottom: y + 'px',
        right: x + 'px'
      });
    }

    function mouseup() {
      $document.unbind('mousemove', mousemove);
      $document.unbind('mouseup', mouseup);
    }
  }
  return {
    link: makeDraggable
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what is the issue with your directive, however providing negative values to the css of your element after drag does work.

```
element.css({
  bottom: -y + 'px',
  right: -x + 'px'
});
```

Check [codepen](http://codepen.io/nashcheez/pen/NpzMPx).

Refer code:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {

});

app.directive('ngDraggable', function($document, $window) {
  function makeDraggable(scope, element, attr) {
    var startX = 0;
    var startY = 0;

    var x = 20;
    var y = 20;

    // Start with a random pos
    // var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 500) + 40);
    // var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 360) + 40);

    element.css({
      position: 'absolute',
      cursor: 'pointer',
      bottom: y + 'px',
      right: x + 'px'
    });

    element.on('mousedown', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      startX = event.pageX - x;
      startY = event.pageY - y;

      $document.on('mousemove', mousemove);
      $document.on('mouseup', mouseup);
    });

    function mousemove(event) {
      y = event.pageY - startY;
      x = event.pageX - startX;

      element.css({
        bottom: -y + 'px',
        right: -x + 'px'
      });
    }

    function mouseup() {
      $document.unbind('mousemove', mousemove);
      $document.unbind('mouseup', mouseup);
    }
  }
  return {
    link: makeDraggable
  };
});
```

```css
img {
  height: 100px;
}

span {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  display: inline-block;
  font: 20px/28px Georgia, serif;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app='myApp'>

<head>
  <title>ng-draggable</title>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <h2>Dragging directive fun</h2>

    <img ng-draggable src="http://fc00.deviantart.net/fs70/i/2012/135/a/7/tux_button_by_blacklite_teh_haxxor-d4zv3fv.png" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I though I tried that, but encountered an issue with the div disappearing completely, but then I realized why. Rather than just doing a -x I was making it a "-" + x

Comment: That would make it a string. We have to preserve the Integer context of the variable here.